# Support for Use of C++ with MPI?

Tags: c++, c, mpi

After spending a good amount of time and effort trying to make my C++ code work with MPI, I've been pointed to the following article (@Johnathan Dursi), http://blogs.cisco.com/performance/the-mpi-c-bindings-what-happened-and-why/, and have basically given up. It takes more effort and thought than simply coding in C (even if the only consideration were to translate the bindings in the code found online, in "Using MPI", and even in "Using MPI-2", supposedly more C++ friendly) and it appears that the folks working on MPI-3 have abandoned the effort to support C++ altogether. Can anyone describe any benefit whatsoever to using C++ while coding an MPI library?

Comment: Coding the project in C++ and using MPI in it have nothing to do with each other. It is equivalent to saying don't use C++ to code your project if you are using OpenGL because OpenGL is C API. However, professionals tend to create state-of-art object-oriented game engines  in C++ which use OpenGL as underlying renderer.

Comment: There is no problem in using the C bindings for MPI from C++.

Comment: You seem to be confused between MPI offering a C++ interface and writing your code in C++. If MPI only offers a C interface that doesn't stop you writing your code in C++. The advantages (or disadvantages) of C++ over C would be the same as for any other case.

Comment: I appreciate these comments, my question was confused.  A better way to express myself would have been to ask if there were any point in using the C++ bindings over the C bindings, especially given that they are no longer supported in more recent versions of MPI?

Comment: @bam54 If the C++ bindings are no longer supported I think that's enough reason not to use them.